# Find wether a function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

**Question**: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and suppose $f : A \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is a function such that there exist real numbers $M \ge 0$ and $r > 1$ such that 
$$||f(x) - f(y)|| \le M||x-y||^r,\quad\forall x,y\in A$$
Prove that $f$ is differentiable and find its total derivative

**Attempt**: for some $c \in A$ we have
 $$0\le \frac{||f(x)-f(c)||}{||x-c||}\le M||x-c||^{r-1}$$
 by squeeze theorem we get that $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{||f(x)-f(c)||}{||x-c||} = 0\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to c}\frac{||f(x)-f(c)-0(x-c)||}{||x-c||}=0$$
 does that prove that $f$ is differentiable with total derivative being $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For differentiability we are supposed to show that $\frac {\|f(x)-f(c)-T(x-c)\|} {\|x-c\|} \to 0$ as $ x\to c$ for some linear transformation $T$. In this case this is true with $T=0$.

Comment: May i ask why that wouldn't be true for some other linear transformation L, isn't it true that x->c leads to L(x-c) -> L(0)=0

Comment: If the derivative exists it is always unique. This requires a simple linear algebra argument and it can be found in any book that discusses derivatives of functions of several variables.

Comment: I know but if we replace 0 in the attempt by some L that isn't 0, don't we still get that limit goes to 0?

Comment: Okay, i got it, thank you very much :)